# Finding all $3\times3$ matrices such that $A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ has two distinct solutions

Tags: matrices

> Find all $3\times3$ matrices $A$ such that
>   $$A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
>   has two distinct solutions.

We know a three variable equation has either $1,0$ or infinite solutions. So can we straightaway say the answer is $0$?

Comment: I think it means "at least two distinct solutions".

Comment: @Dave No.. its written **exactly** two solutions

Comment: Well your questions just says "has two distinct solutions", so if the questions is really asking for exactly two distinct solutions then yeah there are no matrices.

Comment: @Dave How would you do if it was **atleast**?

Comment: Well at least two is the same as asking for infinitely many (by the argument you have since it's either 0,1, or infinitely many).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly two is impossible since if $r_1,\,r_2$ qualify so does $2r_1-r_2$, since $A(2r_1-r_2)=2Ar_1-Ar_2=2i-i=i$ while $2r_1-r_2\ne r_1\iff r_1\ne r_2\iff 2r_1-r_2\ne r_2$.

Comment: What does that imply? I am a beginner ;-)

Comment: @tatan See edit.

Comment: What is $r_1$ and $r_2$?

Comment: @tatan As their introduction said, two hypothetical solutions of $Ar=i$.